# What happens to an object during deserializing?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a question about the `OnDeserializing` attribute. I have a class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Test 
{
    int tmp = 10;

    [OnDeserializing]
    internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        tmp -= 3;  
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", tmp); 
    }
}
```

Serialization works perfectly fine, but the code in the OnDeserializationMethod prints "-3".

Can anyone tell me why that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that upon deserialization, your constructor is not run.

You see, this code:

```
public class Foo
{
    int test = 10;
}
```

Actually gets compiled to this:

```
public class Foo
{
    int test;

    public Foo()
    {
        test = 10;
    }
}
```

But since that constructor isn't run, all member variables start out with their default value, in the case of `int test` being 0.

So then the deserializer calls `OnDeserializingMethod()`, and `test` gets decremented by 3, yielding 0 - 3 = -3.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening cause you are setting a default value of the serialized field and thus the field `tmp` gets set to -3. Per [Documentation on OnDeserializingAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Use the `OnDeserializingAttribute` to set default values during
>   deserialization. For example, if the type that you are deserializing
>   does not contain a constructor, create a method to set values of any
>   fields in the instance and apply the attribute to the method.